# Angular: An Issue about Websocket reconnection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket

I set a timeout function to wait and trigger reconnection after the connection is broken.

My Angular version is 11.

The following is my WebsocketService code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
    
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

        ws.onopen = (event) => {
            console.log('WebSocket connected');
        }

        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(data);
        }

        ws.onclose = (event) => {
            console.log('Close WebSocket connection');
            setTimeout(this.init, 1000);
        }

        ws.onerror = (event) => {
            console.log(`WebSocket connection error: ${event}`);
            ws.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that setTimeout function always be triggered twice.

Then it will not work anymore.

Have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: create a variable and clear the timeout after starting the time out, in your `ws.onclose`  function, you need to clear the previous timeout and start again.

Comment: @AkhilAravind It doesn't work. The variable always get an undefined value from setTimeout.

Comment: How did you tried that, can you share the code block?

Comment: @AkhilAravind I found the answer. I should modify it to `this.timer = setTimeout(this.init.bind(this), 1000);`. Ref: [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-settimeout-function-examples/#analternativemethod)